# Problems when compiling 64 bit (0xc000007b)

Tags: c++, windows, x86-64

I am working on a Kinect Project, which uses MS Kinect SDK and facetracker. The code compiles and runs perfectly on Win32, but I am trying to get it to run in x64. I am using Visual studio and I created this x64 build and updated all library locations to the amd64 ones and it compiles correctly. When I try to run the x64 debug I get the following warning:
[image: Warning]

VS2012 outputs the following:

```
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Users\Jacko\Documents\GitHub\KinectMain\x64\Debug\KinectMain.exe'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\user32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\gdi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\lpk.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\usp10.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcrt.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\Kinect10.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winmm.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\sechost.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\rpcrt4.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\ole32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\oleaut32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcp100.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msvcr100.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\devobj.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\winusb.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\crypt32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\msasn1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\System32\d2d1.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\Developer Toolkit v1.7.0\Redist\x86\FaceTrackLib.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'KinectMain.exe' (Win32): Unloaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\Developer Toolkit v1.7.0\Redist\x86\FaceTrackLib.dll'
The program '[0x17D0] KinectMain.exe' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

Comment: Well this line looks troublesome -
`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Kinect\Developer Toolkit v1.7.0\Redist\x86\FaceTrackLib.dll`
Do you have the 64 bit dll in your path?

Comment: check this post  http://hiankun.blogspot.fr/2013/03/test-kinect-on-win7-x64-using-x86-driver.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading `...\x86\FaceTrackLib.dll` looks suspicious.  If this is a 64-bit program, shouldn't you be loading an x64 or amd64 or x86_64 or whatever it's called DLL?  Take a look on your machine or installation media to see if there is another FaceTrackLib.dll which might be 64-bit.

This is confirmed by Microsoft's document here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj130970.aspx